# Current Month in words and not int

Tags: c#

I'm getting the current month and year from the dateTime and passing it to a string. The reason for this is, in my directory there has to be a folder for the current year and month - this is done in order for video uploading quantity. This is what I currently have:

```
    string month = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.Month);
        string Year = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.Year);
        UploadStatusLabel.Text = Year + "\\" + month;
        //New Directory Name in string variable
        string NewDirectory = Server.MapPath("~\\uploads\\" + Year + "\\" + month);
        //Calling the function to create new directory
        CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(NewDirectory);
```

All this works, but the problem is, is that month displays at 5 which is correct, but I need it to display May. How do I do this?

Comment: The use of "month" and "Year" as variable names is going to give me hives.

Comment: @ dnord - It was changed to dtYear and dtMonth after I added the code here....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at formatting date time into strings: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

This should be what you require for displaying the month 'May':

```
Datetime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
```

Comment: Surprised at the answer not getting upvotes, This is the first and correct answer so +1

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");
```

Depending if you want January or Jan

Answer (score 3):

try something like

```
string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
```

For Advance Knowledge [Click here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

Does `DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM")` work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the ToString() method over the DateTime object, 
For example :

```
Datetime.Now.ToString("yyyy"); // will give you 2013
Datetime.Now.ToString("MMMM"); //will give you 'May'
```

Here is a reference :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: But it will return "Jan" in January , MMMM is the full month name

Answer (score 1):

```
string month= DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```